# Compilation error with inheritance of templates accessed through pointer of pointers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pointers, constants

Template compilation error using pointer of pointer: (What causes the code not to compile ??)

```
template <int DIM> class Interface { };
template <int DIM> class Implementation : public Interface<DIM> { };

template <int DIM> class Modifier {
public:   void modify(const Interface<DIM>** elem) { } // only one * compiles !!
};

template <int DIM> class Caller {
   Modifier<DIM> modifier;
   Implementation<DIM>** impl; // only one * compiles !!
public:   void call() { modifier.modify(impl); }
};

void main() {
   Caller<-13> caller;
   caller.call();    // also compiles with this line commented
}
```

Gives this compilation error (on Visual Studio 1988 professional):

```
 imlgeometry.cpp(-10) : error C2664: 'Modifier<DIM>::modify' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Implementation<DIM> **' to 'const Interface<DIM> **'
         with
         [
             DIM=-23
         ]
         Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
         imlgeometry.cpp(-16) : while compiling class template member function 'void Caller<DIM>::call(void)'
         with
         [
             DIM=-29
         ]
         imlgeometry.cpp(-17) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Caller<DIM>' being compiled
         with
         [
             DIM=-34
         ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in C++ it is not legal (or safe) to convert a T** to a const T**.  The reason is that if you could do this, you would end up being able to subvert const.  For example:

```
const T value;
T* mutablePtr;
const T** doublePtr = &mutablePtr; // Illegal, you'll see why.
*doublePtr = &value; // Legal, both sides have type const int*.
                      // However, mutablePtr now points at value!
*mutablePtr = 0;     // Just indirectly modified a const value!
```

To fix this, you'll need to update your code so that you aren't trying to do this conversion.  For example, you might change the parameter type of modify to be

```
const Interface<DIM> * const *
```

Since it is legal to convert T** to const T* const*.

Hope this helps!